# Translation of output from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm pretty new to both php and mysql and have been searching a couple of days for an answer to this! I'm trying to translate my page and need som help with that!
In PHP it's done with: `<?php echo $lang['event']; ?>` and works great and gets its variables from `language.php`. Within php.echo I use: `{$lang['List synced']}` and that works great too.

And my problem is when I call my DB and get data into my `$row` output, I want to translate this to!

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query1="SELECT event, date, time FROM futelldus_bell ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10 ";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<tr><td class='bold'>" . $row['event'] . "</td><td class='tiny'>" . 
    $row['date'] . "</td><td class='tiny'>" . $row['time'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

It's `$row['xxxx']` I'm stuck at, is there a god way to translate these with my `translate.php`?

Comment: you can try $lang[$row['event']] , what it does is it pick your DB data and pass as Index of $lang, if it found it will show the translated data. but you better look for i18n translation code and library and they give you long term solution.

Comment: Yes it's my translate.php document that does it, what i'm looking for is a wat to change $row with that document! The syntax in translate.php is "date" => "datum", and so on for all the words i want to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$lang` is an array associating string and their translations, you can use

`$lang[$row['event']]`

Note that of course, you will have to have a translation for all possible values of the string in the database.

A good thing to go further with PHP and MySQL would be to learn to use a framework, like CakePHP, Symfony, or Zend. Most of them have translation features in their template engines that will make the work a lot more easier.

Comment: It did work with your solution, i must have made it to complicated when i tried my self... Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you are asking. Supposing that `language.php` contains an associative array `$lang` where the keys are message identifiers and the values are localized messages in your language, if `$row['event']` is a key of `$lang`, you can get the corresponding localized message with `$lang[$row['event']]`.

Too many assumptions in this answer, as it's hard to imagine how your code actually works.